# Generar Display para DateTime que puede ser nulo

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un proyecto en ASP.NET MVC y quiero ejecutar el siguiente código en la vista:

```
<dd>
   @if (!Model.FechaEgreso.HasValue)
   {
      @Html.DisplayName(Model.FechaEgreso.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
   }
   else
   {
      @Html.DisplayName("No corresponde")
   }
</dd>
```

El error que arroja la consola es:

[image]

Claramente, el método ToString() permite un sólo parámetro porque ya lo utilice para:

```
<dd>
   @Html.DisplayName(Model.FechaIngreso.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
</dd>
```

Por eso, supongo que el error es porque el valor puede ser nulo.

Espero que me puedan ayudar a poder hacer el display con el formato que deseo.

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: Confirme que el error es que el dato puede ser nulo, porque si yo ejecuto: `@Html.DisplayFor(model =>model.FechaEgreso)` si funciona. El problema es que yo le quiero dar un formato. No quiero que me muestre la hora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando tienes datos del tipo nullable, utiliza el `.Value` para obtener el valor, mira:

```
@Html.DisplayName(Model.FechaEgreso.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```